# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using Maven imported libraries (Java3D)

Tags: java, maven, import

I've been trying to add some Java 3D dependency libraries in my Maven project, but I am getting an 'UnsatisfiedLinkError'. After some looking around, I think I'm seeing this error because java cannot find some required native libraries (.dll?) in java.libraries.home.

I've seen solutions online about linking my machines PATH to the .dll files (and therefore adding them to my machines java.library.home), but I'm after a solution that will work on any mvn install.

What's confusing me is that I'm using other Maven imported libraries (JGraphT), and they work fine.

Does anyone know a way of automatically adding the native libraries on a maven install? If not, any other solutions to try?

Thanks.

In my pom.xml:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->    
<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>res</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>graphsim.Simulator</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/java3d/j3d-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>java3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>j3d-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/java3d/j3d-core-utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>java3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>j3d-core-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/java3d/vecmath -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>java3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl$22.run(MasterControl.java:889)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:886)
    at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.(VirtualUniverse.java:229)
    at javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D.(Canvas3D.java:3533)
    at gfx.point_viewer.PointFrame.(PointFrame.java:50)
    at gfx.GUIManager.createPointFrame(GUIManager.java:81)
    at gfx.GUIManager.(GUIManager.java:59)
    at graphsim.Simulator.start(Simulator.java:40)
    at graphsim.Simulator.main(Simulator.java:125)
```

Answer (score -1):

So apparently the Java3D library I was using is 'too old' for build tools like Maven, meaning the wrapper libraries were being put in my .m2 directory but none of the functionality was linked.

Easy fix; use a different library.